# Python difflib? Software crash matching

Tags: python, difflib

I have a bunch of SW crashes that i'm trying to match with difflib.

Example:

> **'[Dsp Restart] ULMA[00256]bbiSrioDrv_main_hwcb.c98 EMCA dest_Id 0x4 is unable to receive messages from this'**
>
>  **'[Dsp Restart] ULMA[00256]bbiSrioDrv_main_hwcb.c98 EMCA dest_Id 0xf4 is unable to receive messages from this c4'**
>
>  **'[Dsp Restart] ULMA[00256]<!UPULL1.384!> ull1pemaster_storage.c424 DBC (this_p->_cellInf o[cellIndex]).subF'**

This is only a small subset, but i cant just strip out say the hex characters because I need those. So i was trying to used difflib to match. If I match the first two lines I get over a 90% match.

The problem I'm running into is say finding all the variations of the first two, make a dic of the first text instance seen and count how many total are over the ~90% match. I can't seem to wrap my head around having it look over the list of all crashes and combine all like crashes.

Everyway i've come up with basically still doesn't group the first two as a single like crash.

Using SequenceMatcher from difflib works and its fast, but it's like I said still making a instance for each crash instead of grouping together. Using get_close_matches from difflib works and finds all of them simular ones and makes a single list. But i'm looping over somthing like 100k lines, so it takes FOREVER!!!!

I'd love some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: So basically what you are trying to do is to find all lines that are 90% similar to some reference line? And want to do that fast?

Comment: I want to do it as fast as possible(but i'll take what i can get :P), But also want to make a dictionary key of say the reference line and the count of all crashes that are a 90% match. Or whatever dataset anyone can come up with. I'm stumped.

Comment: Don't know how fast is next solution, but you can do following - install modules through `pip install fuzzywuzzy python-Levenshtein`, run code `import fuzzywuzzy.process; print(fuzzywuzzy.process.extract('abc', ['def', 'abc', 'ab', 'abd']))` it prints `[('abc', 100), ('ab', 90), ('abd', 67), ('def', 0)]`, what it does it takes first argument of extract() as base string and second argument as searching list, then it evaluates how close is base string to each element of search list and outputs sorted list of searched string having score `0-100` showing how close is given string to base string.

Comment: You can basically use this fuzzywuzzy as follows - manually you try to find several base strings that represent well each category of error string, then search each such base string in full 100K list of strings. Those strings that have good score (close to 100) will be close to your base string. Others (lower score) you put aside and feed these others to rest of base strings. Do these process while you have examples of base strings. If you finished and still search list is not empty then you can figure out other base strings, or maybe lower score threshold.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and report back!

Comment: If you'll try my solution don't forget to install TWO modules `pip install fuzzywuzzy python-Levenshtein`, not just one `fuzzywuzzy`, because `python-Levenshtein` is C/C++ optimized code which is fast. If you don't install it then slow pure Python `SequenceMatcher` is used. BTW, the reason that your difflib usage is very slow is because difflib is mostly written in pure Python, not in C/C++. And pure Python can be 50-200 times slower than same C/C++ algorithm.

Comment: I decided I was over complicating it. Used 1 for loop over the dict keys and incremented or added a 1 to each key. 

Before checking if the key exist, used translate to rip out all the special chars, and replace with a dash, split on the dash, convert back to a string. Looks like it's matching ~98% of them and counting them correctly. 

Thanks